# getting error "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist " in java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to learn connecting to oracle database

when I log into sqlplus this way:

`sqlplus sys/Oracle_1@orcl as sysdba;`

I run this code:

`connect hr/hr@orclpdb`

`select count(*) from employees;`

and I get this output:

```
 COUNT(*)
----------
       107
```

but when I'm trying to access this table in my java code I get this error:

`ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

here is my java code:

```
class OracleCon{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@localhost:1521/orclpdb","sys as sysdba","Oracle_1"); 
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from employees");  
while(rs.next())  
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  
con.close();  
}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  

}  
}
```

what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: How is `System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  ` supposed to work if you are only returning one value `count` ?

Comment: actually my problem is that it seems no such table exists

Comment: would also probably help diagnose if you did `e.printStacktrace ()` rather than just printing `e`

Comment: You need to connect as `hr` from your Java program. **NEVER** use the `SYS` account for "normal work".

Comment: tnx for your mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, please,  this code. It's must working

```
public static void conn() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{  
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orclpdb", "HR", "HR"); 
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from dual");  
    while(rs.next())  
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));  
    con.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to connect it using `sys` user in your java code, But table `employee` is present in `hr` schema.

You can either change:

```
//Change this line from

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@localhost:1521/orclpdb","sys as sysdba","Oracle_1"); 

// to

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@localhost:1521/orclpdb","hr","hr");
```

Or

You can change the way you are fetching the data from table `employee` (query the table with its schema)

```
//Change this line from
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from employees"); 
//to
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from hr.employees");
```

Cheers!!